# Probability of picking one of *p* good hockey teams from *N* teams with *k* attempts.

Tags: probability

This is actually a question coined by my friend while playing NHL on an x-box. Before every match, we are randomly picking teams. The process of picking goes as follows: Consider *N* teams to get, *p* **good** teams, and *k* attempts to get at least one of *p* **good** teams. However, when you randomly get team **S** at *i*-th and *j*-th attempt (1<=*i*<*j*<=*k*), you get another free attempt.

To make it more specific:

Lets have *N*=22 national teams and only *p*=4 (Russia, Sweden, USA, Canada) **good** teams. What is the probability of getting at least one of the *p*=4 **good** teams from *k*=5 attempts?

Comment: Hint: it is $1$ minus the probability that no good team is picked.

Comment: And another hint: if you when you get a repeat, you are allowed to pick again, that means you are picking "without replacement": think of your teams as balls in an urn (probability experts love balls in urns). Each time you pick, you put the ball aside, not back in the urn, so it isn't possible to get it on your next pick. Your repicking rule accomplishes the same thing, just in a more awkward fashion.